# why won't run my react-native android app in my custom phone emulator

Tags: react-native

it's worked but suddenly without any reason stop working
my error in cmd is this:
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to establish session

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32577761/com-android-ddmlib-installexception-failed-to-establish-session-react-native

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to establish session react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32577761/com-android-ddmlib-installexception-failed-to-establish-session-react-native)